# How to get to objects in inflater

Tags: android, seekbar, layout-inflater

I sent up an infalter each inflater has a row that had a seekbar and textviews.  I can't figure out how to get to the seekbar in the second row.  I wrote a seekOnChangeListener, but it only applies to the last seekbar in the infalter.  How to get to object in other rows?

```
            @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            int barChosen = seekBar.getId();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float changePerPersonTip = Float.parseFloat(tipTotal);
            changePerPersonTip  *= progress;
            changePerPersonTip  /= 100;
            changePerPersonTip = (float) (Math.round(changePerPersonTip * 100.0) / 100.0);
            String changeInPerPerson = Float.toString(changePerPersonTip);
            tipPerPerson.setText(changeInPerPerson);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You said "each row", do you inflate from a layout with a listview or a table layout ?

You could have something like this:

```
private class ViewHolderRowItem{
    SeekBar sb;
    TextView txt1;
    TextView txt2;///...etc
    View layout;///...a container if needed
}
```

In the getView method of an adapter (e.g. for your listview) you could have:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderRowItem holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.data_row_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolderGridItem();
            holder.sb = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sb);
            holder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            holder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        }
     }
```

For the TableLayout approach (you know the columns and rows of your layout), for instance (3 columns), you could use the methods [getChildCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) and [getChildAt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) to retrieve each cell of your table:

```
TableLayout tbL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbL);
TableRow row1=(TableRow)tbL.getChildAt(0);
SeekBar sb1=(SeekBar) row1.getChildAt(0);
TextView txt1_1=(TextView) row1.getChildAt(1);
TextView txt1_2=(TextView) row1.getChildAt(2);
..etc
```

You could iterate on the different rows of your table like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<tbL.getChildCount();++i){
 TableRow row= (TableRow) tbL.getChildAt(i);
 SeekBar sb=(SeekBar) row.getChildAt(0);
 TextView txt1=(TextView) row.getChildAt(1);
 TextView txt2=(TextView) row.getChildAt(2);
}
```

Comment: You could use the above code to retrieve the rows of your table layout (from the getLayoutInflater() call) as you know their Ids .
If you know the number of rows it's fine, otherwise, you could consider a listview.

Comment: I take it postion is the row.

Comment: You can use TableLayout tbL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbL); to identify your table layout ([doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)) and then use the methods tbL.getChildAt(row_number).getChildAt(column_number) to navigate in your table. I'll add this to my answer